# Launch Azurite with command line from Visual Studio 2022

Tags: azure-storage, visual-studio-2022, azurite, connected-services

VS 2022 has a "Connected Services" feature that allows adding Azurite and launching it. When adding Azurite NPM installation to VS connected services, it doesn't give you the option to specify any command line.

I am only interested in launching Azurite in HTTPS mode, so I am interested in something like this:

`"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Azure Storage Emulator\azurite.exe" --cert C:/programdata/Cert/127.0.0.1.pem --key C:/programdata/Cert/127.0.0.1-key.pem`

Where or how can I modify the command line launcher in VS to include specific parameters?

Comment: Is this [reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azurite?tabs=visual-studio) works for you!